# Prove or disprove: If $ f $ is periodic, then $|f|$ is also periodic.

Tags: analysis, absolute-value, periodic-functions

I started with the definition of periodic function and absolute value function. And I do it with discussing different cases of $x$ and $p$. But I got stuck with when $ -p\leq x <0  $ , I want to show $ |f(x+p) |= |f(x)| $.

Comment: You can prove something stronger: If $f$ is periodic, then $g\circ f$ is periodic _no matter what_ $g$ is. In this case $g$ is the absolute-value function, but it looks vaguely like you're confusing yourself by considering particular properties of the absolute value. In that case it should be _easier_ for you to prove the stronger claim, where $g$ is just some arbitrary function.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to use the definition of $f$ being periodic? I can hardly see how you could go wrong if you just apply the definition.

Answer (score 1):

let $p$ be our periodicity and $h=g\circ f$ with $f$ being periodict, we then have that
$$h(n+p)=g\circ f (n+p)=g(f(n+p))=g(f(n))=g\circ f (n) = h(n)$$
so our composition is also periodic, in our case we have $g(x)=|x|$

Comment: You mean $h = g \circ f$ at the very beginning!

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about! *whistles innocently* Thank you for pointing it out